# Firestore still retrieving documents from cache even though I've disabled persistence

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

My Firestore is still retrieving documents from cache even though I've explicitly told it not to:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val dbSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(false).build()
        db.firestoreSettings = dbSettings
```

Above is my launcher activity where I set the Firestore settings.

In my fragment I perform a [`GeoFirestore GeoQuery`](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android#geo-queries):

```
class MapFragment : Fragment() {
    val instances = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("instances")
    val geoFirestore = GeoFirestore(instances)
    lateinit var nearbyDocs: GeoQuery

    private fun searchNearby(){
        nearbyDocs = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(currentLocation, 1.0)
        nearbyDocs.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(object : GeoQueryDataEventListener {

            override fun onDocumentEntered(documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot, location: GeoPoint) {
               Log.d(TAG, "onDocumentEntered: user1: ${documentSnapshot.getString("user1")?.substring(0, 3)} | docId: ${documentSnapshot.id.substring(0, 5)} | fromCache: ${documentSnapshot.metadata.isFromCache}")
               Log.d(TAG, "isPersistanceEnabled2: ${db.firestoreSettings.isPersistenceEnabled}")
            }
    }
```

This is what it logs:

```
onDocumentEntered: user1: 0X6 | docId: lPLFf | fromCache: true
isPersistanceEnabled2: false
```

This doesn't make sense - I'm receiving cached documents even though my persistence is turned off.

Any idea what the problem is?

**Edit**: I have tried clearing the cache but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain exactly how you are observing that documents are definitely coming from the cache and not the server.

Comment: Edited - when it happens again I will include the cached document log.

Comment: Probably, Doug didn't see your response since you haven't tagged him with `@`. He could have helped, I guess

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my answer with some examples of cache retrievals

Answer (score 4):

You are now able to choose if you would like to fetch your data from the server only, or from the cache only, like this (an example for server only):

```
DocumentReference documentReference= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("example");
documentReference.get(Source.SERVER).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            //...
    }
});
```

For cache only, just change the code above to Source.CACHE.

**By default, both methods still attempt server and fall back to the cache.**

Comment: Thanks this would solve my problem - but I'm using a library for my queries: https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android so I don't have direct access to my code.

Comment: @Zorgan, since geofirestore doesn't have an option to force server reads, you can simply add this library as a module and change this specific part